# Is this proof correct (Set of sequences with a metric $\sup{|x_{n} – y_{n}|}$)?

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be the set of all bounded sequences $x_{n}$ with real entries. We define a metric d on X by saying that d($\{x_{n}\}, \{y_{n}\}$) = $\sup{|x_{n} – y_{n}|: n \in \mathbb{N}}$. 
Let $E_{n}$ be the set of all sequences ${x_{n}} \in X$ such that $x_{n}=0$ for all $ n \ge N$. Let $\{a_{n}\} \in X$. Prove that {$a_{n}$} belongs to the closure of $\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{n}}$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\{a_{n}\} = 0}$.

Proof:

First I will prove that $\overline{\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{n}}} = {\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{n}}}^\prime = \cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{n}} \cup \{0, 0, ...\}$, and then "iff" part.

Consider $E_{n}$.

$E_{2} = \{x_{2 1}, 0, 0, … : x_{2 1} \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

$E_{3} = \{x_{3 1}, x_{3 2},  0, 0, … : x_{3 j} \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

$E_{2} = \{x_{4 1}, x_{4 2}, x_{4 3}, 0, 0, … : x_{4 j} \in \mathbb{R}\}$ etc.

Since for $i \ne j$ $E_{i} \cap E_{j} = \emptyset$, $\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{N}} = \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} E_{N} $.

So $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{N}} = \{ \{x_{2 1}, 0, 0, …\}, \{x_{3 1},  x_{3 2}, 0, 0, …\}, … :x_{i j} \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Denote $\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{N}}$ as A. Let $b_{n} \in A$.

Pick $\{b_{n}\} \in E_{j}$ and  $\{b_{n}^{\prime}\} \in E_{j}$.

It means that $b_{n}$ and $b_{n}^\prime \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n <  j$, $b_{n}$ and $b_{n}^\prime = 0$ for $n \ge j$.

Pick $b_{n}$ and $b_{n}^\prime$, such that $b_{n} = b_{n}^\prime$ if $n < j - 1$ and $b_{n} = b_{n} - \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$ if $n = j - 1$.

Then d($\{b_{n}\}, \{b_{n}^\prime \}$) = $\sup{|b_{n} – b_{n}^\prime|} = \epsilon$.

By setting $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small we can make $b_{n}$ and $b_{n}^{\prime}$ as close as we want.

This proves that each {$b_{n}$} is a limit point of A and kind of proves that A is an open set.

Claim: the only limit point of A, which does not belong to A, is a sequence $\{0, 0, ...\}$.

Pick $b_{n} \in A$, such that $b_{n} = \{\epsilon, 0, 0, ...\}$ for $\epsilon > 0$. Then $d(\{0, 0, ...\}, \{\epsilon, 0, 0, ...\}) = \epsilon$. We can make it as small as we want, so for an open ball $N_{\epsilon}$: $N_{\epsilon}(\{0, 0, ...\}) \cap A \ne \emptyset$

Since $d(\{x_{n}\}, \{y_{n}\}) = \sup {|x_{n} - y_{n}|}$, $d(\{x_{n}\}, \{y_{n}\}) \in (0, \infty)$.

Thus the only limit point of B outside of A is $\{0, 0, ...\}$, since for and arbitrary distance d from a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ we can find some sequence $\{y_{n}\}$ with a distance of $d + \epsilon$ from $\{x_{n}\}$.

So I proved that $A^\prime = A \cup \{0, 0, ...\}$. Thus $\bar{A} = A \cup \{0, 0, ...\}$.

Now: Prove that {$a_{n}$} belongs to the closure of $\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} {E_{n}}$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\{a_{n}\} = 0}$.

Proof of: If ${a_{n} \in \bar{A}}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} = 0$.

Definition: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} = 0$ means that $\forall \epsilon$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that if $n \ge N$, then $|a_{n} - 0| < \epsilon $.

If $\{a_{n}\} \in \bar{A}$, then either $\{a_{n}\} \in A$ or ${a_{n}} = \{0, 0, ...\}$. In the first case it means that $\{a_{n}\}$ is eventually zero, in the second case it means that for any N $\{a_{n}\}$ is zero. So this part is proved.

Proof of: if $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} = 0$, then $\{a_{n}\} \in \bar{A}$.

Probably this is very stupid question about the very basic concept of a limit, but is it true that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} = 0$, then eventually $\{a_{n}\}$ is equal to zero? I mean, I know that $\{a_{n}\}$ becomes infinitely close to zero after some N, and I need to prove that eventually it is equal to zero - so is it just automatic proof by definition of a limit?

Can you please say whether the whole proof is correct and all steps are valid and well-proven?

Comment: It seems that the $E_i $ and $E_j $ are not disjoint, but rather they are subsets of each other. Also, what does sum notation for sets mean? It seems you don't use these two facts in the proof anyway.

Comment: I think I used the sum notation wrong. I just wanted to show that I think that all these subsets are disjoint (but I am not sure about this).

Comment: I do not think they are disjoint, but more importantly I think your proof is fundamentally flawed because $A$ is not open. For example, if I start with $a = (1,0,0,0,0,\dots) \in E_2$ then the element $a_\varepsilon = (1,\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\dots)$ is not contained in any $E_j$ but is $\varepsilon$ close to $a$.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right and A is not open. As to the union of these sequences, I do not understand at all how to take a union of sets of sequences - should we regards each sequence in the set as some object of a set and just put all of these objects together to get a union, or we can "open" these sequences. Just to understand this question: if we have two sets with two sequences each: C = $\{\{1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{2.1, 0, 0, ...\}\}$ and D = $\{\{1, 1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{2.1, 1.4, 0, 0, ...\}\}$, will their union consist of 2 or 4 sequences?

Comment: I mean, is $C \cup D = \{\{1, 1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{2.1, 1.4, 0, 0, ...\}\}$ or $C \cup D = \{\{1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{2.1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{1, 1, 0, 0, ...\}, \{2.1, 1.4, 0, 0, ...\}\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\lim_na_n=0.$ For any $n\ge 1$ consider the sequence $$(b_n)=(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1},0,0,\cdots,0,\cdots)\in E_n.$$ Since $\lim_na_n=0$ given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies |a_n|<\epsilon.$ In other words given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies d((a_n),(b_n))<\epsilon.$ So, $(a_n)$ is in the closure of $\cup_{n}E_n.$

Conversely, assume that $(a_n)$ is in the closure of $\cup_{n}E_n.$ So, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a sequence $(b_n)\in \cup_{n}E_n$ such that $d((a_n),(b_n))<\epsilon.$ But there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N\implies b_n=0.$ In other words, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that

$$n\ge N\implies |a_n|\le d((a_n),(b_n))<\epsilon.$$ That is, $\lim_na_n=0.$